# Power BI - Data model does not return value of matching key but all records instead

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerpivot, datamodel

I am totally new to Power BI. So I may be asking really basic questions. I do have some experience in SQL, Excel, MS Access. That maybe the reason why I am confused here.

I made a Power Query with an unique key called Item_M. I made an exact copy of this query and added both to the data model. I linked Item_M from both queries.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXFcF.png)

In the pivot table on this data model I would expect to see for each Item_M from the first query, the exact same Item_M from the second query in the next column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA8oG.png)

However as you can see this is not the case. Instead the second column it just listed all the Item_M's from the second query.

In the example I would expect to see "12000     CMW KZ" in column 1 and row 1. And in column2 also "12000     CMW KZ"

Your helps is much appreciated.

PS. it maybe strange to link the same queries in a datamodel. But I was troubleshooting a different relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about this, because I can't see how the fields have been placed in the table, however, the relationship has a direction (or better a "cross filter direction".
In your case

- ...P10000 (let's call this A)
- ...P11000 (let's call this B)

The relationship is in single direction from A→B
This means that

- a filter applied on A is propagated to B (through the key)
- a filter applied on B is NOT propagated to A

If you want the two tables to filter each other regardless of the "order" you can set the "cross filter direction" to "both", but is not really suggested as this adds more things to take into consideration and could make formulas behave "strangely"

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the explanation Giovanni.

Comment: DId it solve the issue? or do you still have problems?